# How to set post tags by some meta keys?

Tags: wordpress

I prepared following code to overwrite post tags following several meta keys.
Now, it works for only one meta key.  How can I apply it to several meta keys?

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID; 
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); // here, adding array_filter to remove empty get_post_meta results
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags, false );
?>
```

By above code, meta value of meta key aaaaa only applied as post tag, and meta value of meta key bbbbb and ccccc is ignored.

---

After I hear advise below, I tried this code too.

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags, false );   

?>
```

Then, all tag is eliminatd.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right, but I suggest that you check if the meta key bbbbb and ccccc does have value or not int he first place. So try to display something like that.

Also, give this a go and try to add one tag in time.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_post_tags/

Like this:

```
    <?php
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID; 

    $tag = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
    if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

    $tag = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb ', $single);
    if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

    $tag = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
    if (!empty() ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

    ?>
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but all tag is gone.  I like to write over all post  tags by custome meta value.  Thank you for your advise, but I may need to use wp_set_post_tags rather than wp_add_post_tags.

Comment: I believe that the tag or taxonomy you are updating only accepts 1 value that's why always the fist value is taken and the others are not. It's not a coincidence that only the AAAA tag is being accepted. Can you post a picture or confirm this? are you using the native WP tags?

Comment: Thank you so much to share your time for my issue.  I should have get text rather than array in this case, so I changed third argument to true, and it starts to work!  Thank you so much for your kindness!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you.

```
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $array_tags_and_ids = [
        $post_id => ["aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc"]
    ];
    foreach ($array_tags_and_ids as $key => $value) {
        // re-call the value and get only the text value
        $implode_tags_names = implode( ', ', $value );

        // wordpress function
        wp_set_post_tags( $key, $implode_tags_names, true );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise, but it works for aaaaa only, and other meta key is ignored. When I change order, it works for other meta key. I dont know why but only meta key of first line works by your code.

Comment: Hi Thank you for thinking about it.  I tried your updated code, it registers "aaaaa", "bbbbb" and "ccccc" as tag text.  I think my poor English made it confused.  "aaaaa" is meta key.  I think your first suggested code was very close to right function.  I will show it below.  I changed third argument to true (default was false ), and it started to work.

Answer (score -1):

I changed third argument to true(default is false), and it started to work!

like this

```
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'aaaaa', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'bbbbb', true );
$tags[] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ccccc', true ); 
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) );
wp_set_post_tags($post_id , $tags, false );
```